# How to get selected value from customized Dropdown in node.js

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

I have customized DropDown in html

```
<button>Select your city</button>
    <ul>
       <li class="custom-radio">
        <input name="item-brand-name" type="radio" id="create0221">
        <label for="create0221">Bradford</label>
        </li>
        <li class="custom-radio">
         <input name="item-brand-name" type="radio" id="create0231">
         <label for="create0231">Cambridge</label>
          </li>
          <li class="custom-radio">
          <input name="item-brand-name" type="radio" id="create0241">
          <label for="create0241">Chester</label>
          </li>
           <li class="custom-radio">
           <input name="item-brand-name" type="radio" id="create0251">
           <label for="create0251">Durham</label>
           </li>
           <li class="custom-radio">
           <input name="item-brand-name" type="radio" id="create0261">
           <label for="create0261">Glasgow</label>
           </li>
        </ul>
```

Now I want to get selected li's value and save into database. like in Textbox I use `name="textbox1"` and `ng-model="user.textbox1"`.
I am sending data in node.js using ng-model.
Please tell me how to achieve the same with customized Dropdown. There is a button when click on that button the dropdown list will appear then select a li. That selected li's value will replace the value of button.

Thanks

Comment: You mean that the button text will be replaced with the selected li's value, and you want to get this value?

Comment: yeah... exactly

Comment: So you can simply get the button text and send it to the server. What's the hard part do you think?

Comment: No. I don't know its hard or simple. I didn't do it before. so I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: As I can see, you are using angular on client side, right? How can you achieve the effect of changing the button text to the selected li? I think you can simply add some more thing to that event handler

Comment: yes, for client side I am using Angular. But I am using Jquery for button event handler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126299/discussion-between-saurabh-sharma-and-hoang-do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you will make a dropdown using ul and li. They are used to create list not dropdown. You need a *select* tag with ng-repeat.

```
<select ng-change="fruitselect(fruitname)" ng-model="fruitname">
    <option ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" value="{{fruit}}">{{fruit}}</option>
</select>
```

And in js,

```
$scope.fruits = ['apple', 'orange','banana', 'grapes', 'plum'];

$scope.fruitselect = function(){

  alert('Ohh. You like ' + $scope.fruitname);
  // then an http call to send data to server
  $http.post('url',$scope.fruitname)
       .then(function(response){
       //do something
     })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per read your question and comment conversation i have made this, please let me know.

```js
var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('exampleCtrl', exampleCtrl);
exampleCtrl.$inject = [];
function exampleCtrl(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.testData = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  vm.selectedItem = vm.testData[0];
  vm.changeEvent = function (item){
    vm.selectedItem = item;
  }
}
app.directive('uiDropdown', uiDropdown);
uiDropdown.$inject=[];
function uiDropdown (){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      var ulDropdown = element.next("[ui-dropdown-data]");
      element.on('click', function() { // Click on ui-dropdown
        ulDropdown[0].style.display = ulDropdown[0].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
      });
      ulDropdown.on('click', function (data) { //click on ui-dropdown-data
        ulDropdown[0].style.display = 'none';
      });
      element.parent().on('mouseleave', function () { // leave parent div
        ulDropdown[0].style.display = 'none';
      });
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="main">
  <div ng-controller="exampleCtrl as vm">
    <div ui-dropdown style="cursor:pointer; border:1px solid; width:50px;">{{vm.selectedItem}}</div>
    <ul style="display: none;margin: 1px;list-style-type: none;padding: 0px;" ui-dropdown-data>
      <li style="border:1px dotted;width:50px; cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="item in vm.testData" ng-click="vm.changeEvent(item)">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    
    <h2>You have selected : {{vm.selectedItem}}</h2>
    <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. In above code you created a  directive for customized dropdown. So now I want to know how to get the selected value in angular.js. I mean how to add `ng-model` in `<div>`

Comment: It's pretty simple, i have updated my answer, please replay it.